# CSS ?ver=4.7.3 not found

Tags: css

I've moved my website to a cloud service, and after moving files, database, and updating database I get one of theme CSS file not found, and a suffix has been added to it with the WordPress version "?ver=4.7.3".

How can I solve that?

Comment: Can you add to your question your functions.php where the CSS is included ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file working without query string then you can remove the query string by adding the following into functions.php

```
// Remove WP Version From Styles    
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );

// Function to remove version numbers
function sdt_remove_ver_css_js( $src ) {
    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
```

or you can try a plugin which does same. [Remove Query Strings From Static Resources](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/)